# Angular 10 page is frozen

Tags: angular, freeze

Sometimes I have the problem that I can't click anything on my page.
After reloading the page, sometimes close and open it again, everything is ok. But after different times the page freeze again.

Nothing works, not hover effects, clicks, or cursor styles. Nothing.

It is an Angular 10 Project.

Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

Now I saw an error in the console after building and uploading my Project. The error is a 404 for a valid route with and without parameters. Can someone help me with this?

Eventuelly this crashs the page?

And after reloading the page with parameters it gives a `GET 404 error`.

Comment: Have you checked Console on browser? What is logged on Console during this process?

Comment: You probably are facing memory leaks. Check that you are unsubscribing from **ALL** `Observables`

Comment: @LuDeveloper Theres not any message in the console in this time.

Comment: @OwenKelvin I will check that again, I fix some unsubscribe last day but it freeze againg.

Comment: This might sometimes occur due to unhandled errors. Check if there are any.

Comment: @RajaShekar Now I see theres an error, but only after building and uploading the project. Eventuelle this is the problem. He said "Fail to Load Resource" for an valid routing with parameters.

Comment: use try catch. It will also help you to find better way a bug.

Comment: @HassanAli and where the try catch? The error occures if i reload my page with parameters.

Comment: can you please add the code? I need to check.

Comment: @HassanAli I can't add the Code because its not the code. Every Route with parameters give an 404 Error that the Route failed to loaded. The route loaded, but I have this error in the console, everytime I reload the page.

Comment: Hi, have you solved the problem? I just saw you updated the question, and just read conversations here. What is the latest status of you project in terms of routing with params?

Comment: @LuDeveloper I don't fixed this problem with the routing but I found the problem for the freezing. It was a simple "event.stopPropagation()" in my header. So i removed this, because I don't need it.

Comment: @LuDeveloper but after refreshing the page it freeze again...but it's not longer freezing in the middle of the process...

Comment: You mentioned in edit that there is an 404 error about routing displayed on Console. So I can recommend you to check the way what is used when transmit a data in routing parameter. An example tutor in short: https://angular.io/start/start-routing#associate-a-url-path-with-a-component